# Why is Python's default installer 32 bit?

Tags: python, 64-bit

If you go to [Python's default installer download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and click the nice yellow button as shown below, it will download you the 32 bit installer for the latest version of Python.

[image]

To get the 64 bit installer, you'd have to click into the link circled in red below and then scroll to the bottom to find the installer, e.g., for windows, it would be *Windows x86-64 executable installer*

[image]

Are most Python developers are still on 32 bit systems? Otherwise, why doesn't Python make the default installer for 64 bit? It certainly confused me for 30 mins, to install the 32 bit version, uninstall and then finally installing the 64 bit version.

Comment: "most people are on 64 bit OS now" - do you have evidence for this?

Comment: This is very similar to the class of "why did the developers of language-X make design-decision Y?" questions, which we don't permit here (they're effectively asking a piece of trivia, rather than a *practical* question about a problem you actually face). To put it differently -- knowing the answer to this question won't help you practice programming any differently than you do already; thus, the question isn't a *practical* one.

Comment: See [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as primarily opinion-based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334) on [meta] for a discussion; granted, this isn't a *spec* question, but the same reasoning applies.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, good point, updated my question.

Comment: Python is supposed to run in a lot of devices, not only in 64 machines bits.

Comment: Windows very much supports running 32-bit programs on a 64-bit install and maintain 32-bit library support / emulation layers. The converse doesn’t hold. So even if “most” run on 64-bit systems, “even more” run on systems that can run 32-bit executables. This is especially true of Windows. Heck, Visual Studio *only* comes in a 32-bit version.

Comment: Once there is a reason to make the user choose (eg. target systems are fundamentally incompatible), such will be forced up front. As of now, it’s simply opt-in that some (not everyone) might benefit from.

Comment: Why are you so concerned about getting the 64 bit version anyway?

Comment: I have the same question. What is the reasoning behind using 32 bit as the default version? 
Most systems today are 64 bit. 
Installing a 32 bit version, as far as I know, limits the about of RAM you can use to 2GB. I can't see any good reason to install a 32 bit version when there is a 64 bit version available. 
The question is not an opinion and should be re-opened.

Comment: this is a good question, and the PC police of stack overflow has censored yet another discussion. :/

Comment: @EmanuelLindström , I think you have a confusion. 32 bit *CPU* limit the RAM capacity to 2GB and not any application or software that is developed for 32 bit CPU's

Comment: @Indominus , Well the answer is simple. If any person goes to their website to download  python, they would set that application in the default link that is supported by maximum number of computers. The point is that a 64 bit application can run on only 64 bit CPUs but a 32 bit application can run on both 32 and 64 bit CPUs . Also , there is no bottle necking or incompatibilities that you will have with the 32 bit version and not with the 64 bit version.

Comment: @Indominus, And then you might have a question why 64bit installers even exists then. Well, the main reason is transition. As time passes by , 32 bit CPU's will become extinct completely .(Like Windows XP ).  So when the time comes , they will set the default link to 64bit

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/dev-python/c/f6_KsvLEuYs?pli=1

Comment: https://github.com/python/pythondotorg/issues/1299